# Scroll particular menuItem to top in navigationView when onDrawerOpened() called

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

I am using **NavigationView** (android.support.design.widget.NavigationView) in DrawerLayout. I am wondering if there is anyway to scroll at particular item programmatically, when user open the drawer. (while **onDrawerOpened()** called in activity)

For instance, when user opens the drawer, I want MenuItem "action_feedback" at the top of DrawerLayout (Scrolled to Top).

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_current_list"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_current_list"
        android:title="@string/current_list" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_manage_lists"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_lists"
        android:title="@string/my_lists" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search_products"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/search_products" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_deals"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_product_promo"
        android:title="@string/deals" />
</group>
<group android:id="@+id/nav_footer"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_feedback"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_feeback"
        android:title="@string/feedback" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sign_out"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sign_out"
        android:title="@string/sign_out" />
</group>
```

Earlier I had Custom Layout (ScrollView + ListView) in DrawerLayout, and It was possible using **scrollView.scrollTo(x,y)**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
private NavigationView vNavigation;

// ...

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
{
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)vNavigation.getChildAt(0);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(4, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the head up. I had tried this way, but didn't scroll the element to top. Do I need to refresh the recycler view data? I tried recycleView.getAdepter().notifyStateChanged(), but no luck!!

Comment: Updated my answer. Previous answer was working but it required your item to not be visible at all. Current approach will work just like scrolling with ListView - and is what you probably expect.

Comment: If you like to keep things .. smooooth ..

Instead of 
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(4, 0);

Try 
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
                            @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                                return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
                            }
                        };
                        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
                        layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);